# How to return multiple rows from a table in in php using mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database, web

I've decided to build a website for fantasy football for my family but am getting stuck with returning multiple rows from the database.

What I want: to make a single sql call and get the entire list of players so I can populate an object or list of objects. (if the whole table could be returned that would be great...). My goal is to have the list of available players to be drafted simply displayed to the user.

Currently I can somewhat see some results when testing by the following method (credit: from the php docs...). However I can't help be feel lost as to what is going on.. I can't make this make sense in my brain.

```
// My query
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM players");

//$data = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql, MYSQL_NUM)) {
    printf("Name: %s <br/>", $row[1]);
}
```

This seems to print the names of each player. However how does 
'mysql_fetch_array()' iterate each row as the while loop iterates? Further, since there are multiple columns how can I access each column... does this have to be hardcoded such as:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql, MYSQL_NUM)) {
    printf("Name: %s <br/>", $row[1]);
    printf("Team: %s <br/>", $row[2]);
    ..
    .
    printf("Team: %s <br/>", $row[5]);
}
```

Eventually I will replace the print statements with code that will store relevant date in a roster object or something:

```
class Roster(){

    $playerName;
    $team;
    $etc.
}
```

The while loop method above feels difficult and clunky. Is there a better way to access all returned rows? How would someone else attempt this? My limited experience is C# and sql server, which can do some amazing stuff with some effortless configuration... immediately return a list ^

If I'm not clear I will check back soon and comment further. I'm still a CS student. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: The `mysql_*` functions will be [deprecated in PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated). It is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future. Instead, either the [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this,

```
 while($row_data = mysql_fetch_array($row_data))
 {
  $row_player_name = $row_data['column_name_player'];
  $row_team = $row_data['column_team'];
  echo $row_player_name;
  echo $row_team;
}
```

column_name_player is the column name of table which contains player name.

Comment: `mysql_fetch_array` is a much better option as you no longer are required to keep you database table columns in a certain order

Comment: mysql_fetch_array will fetch both the mysql_fetch_row and mysql_fetch_assoc results. You may want to stick with just using mysql_fetch_assoc if you want to index your results by column name.

Answer (score 3):

Although as Jason Suggested, please do not use mysql_* functions. But just to clarify your concept

```
        // My query
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM players");

        //$data = mysql_fetch_array($sql);

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql, MYSQL_NUM)) {
                printf("Name: %s <br/>", $row[1]);
        }
```

This is complicated for a beginner unnecessarily. Instead of using row indexes like 1 or 2 or 3 you can (and probably should) simply use your field names there.

So update it to like

```
        // My query
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM players");

        //$data = mysql_fetch_array($sql);

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
                echo "Name:". $row["name"];
                echo "Other Data:". $row["otherdata"];
                echo "<br>";
        }
```

Ofcourse **name** and **otherdata** are just assumed. You will replace them with your actual field names from table

Comment: OK I will work further with this. Thanks to the several people that responded so quickly.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to retrieve every column in every row without having to know each column name, you can count the number of columns in the table.

```
$queryCols = "SHOW COLUMNS FROM players":
$queryPlayers = "SELECT * FROM players";
$result = mysql_query($queryPlayers);
$playerColumns = mysql_query($queryCols);
$colsResult = mysql_fetch_row($playerCols);
$numFields = count($colsResult);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  for ($i = 0; $i < $numFields; $i++) {
    $row[$i]; // Each column in each row
  }
}
```

---

Here an example of a `mysqli` select statement which is the successor to the *soon to be deprecated* `mysql_* statements`:

```
$DB_NAME = 'test';
$DB_HOST = 'localhost';
$DB_USER = 'root';
$DB_PASS = '';

$mysqli = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
 printf('Connection to $s using %s@$s failed: %s\n', 
  $DB_NAME, $DB_USER, $DB_HOST, mysqli_connect_error());
 exit();
}

$query = "SELECT `fname`, `lname`, `team` FROM `players`;";

if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)) {
 $stmt->execute();
 $stmt->bind_result($fname, $lname, $team);
 $table = <<< TABLE
<table border="1">
  <thead><tr>
   <th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>Team</th>
  </tr></thead>
  <tbody>
TABLE;
 while ($stmt->fetch()) {
  $table .= "<tr><td>$fname</td><td>$lname</td><td>$team</td></tr>";
 }
 $table .= "</tbody></table>";
 printf($table);
 $stmt->close();
} else {
  printf("Prepared Statement Error: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
}
```

Table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `players` (
  `id` int(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fname` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `lname` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `team` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=13 ;

INSERT INTO `players` (`id`, `fname`, `lname`, `team`) VALUES
(1, 'Peyton', 'Manning', 'Denver Broncos'),
(2, 'Matt', 'Ryan', 'Atlanta Falcons'),
(3, 'Tom', 'Brady', 'New England Patriots'),
(4, 'Colin', 'Kaepernick', 'San Francisco 49ers'),
(5, 'Matt', 'Schaub', 'Houston Texans'),
(6, 'Aaron', 'Rodgers', 'Green Bay Packers'),
(7, 'Joe', 'Flacco', 'Baltimore Ravens'),
(8, 'Robert', 'Griffin III', 'Washington Redskins'),
(9, 'Andrew', 'Luck', 'Indianapolis Colts'),
(10, 'Matt', 'Flynn', 'Seattle Seahawks'),
(11, 'Andy', 'Dalton', 'Cincinnati Bengals'),
(12, 'Christian', 'Ponder', 'Minnesota Vikings');
```

The Results:

```
First Name  Last Name   Team
Peyton      Manning     Denver Broncos
Matt        Ryan        Atlanta Falcons
Tom         Brady       New England Patriots
Colin       Kaepernick  San Francisco 49ers
Matt        Schaub      Houston Texans
Aaron       Rodgers     Green Bay Packers
Joe         Flacco      Baltimore Ravens
Robert      Griffin III Washington Redskins
Andrew      Luck        Indianapolis Colts
Matt        Flynn       Seattle Seahawks
Andy        Dalton      Cincinnati Bengals
Christian   Ponder      Minnesota Vikings
```

Comment: you are missing a `"` at the end of `$queryPlayers = "SELECT * FROM players;`

Answer (score 0):

```html
//This function will print 5 rows 10 columns 

$n = 5; 
$m = 10;
$tr='';
 
 for($r=0; $r<$n; $r++)
  {
 $td='';  
  
   for ($c=0; $c<$m; $c++)
        {
  $td = $td."<td>".$c.$r."</td>";
  }
   
    $tr =$tr."<tr>".$td. "</tr>";
 }

 echo $otp = "<table border='0'>".$tr."</table>";
```

Comment: This piece of script converts [5x10] matrix query results to [10X5] matrix

Comment: for example 
select a, b, c, d, e from table_name limit 10 will produce result as below

00 10 20 30 40
01 11 21 31 41
02 12 22 32 42
03 13 23 33 43
04 14 24 34 44
05 15 25 35 45
06 16 26 36 46
07 17 27 37 47
08 18 28 38 48
09 19 29 39 49

Above Script will converts to 

00 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90
01 11 21 31 41 51 61 71 81 91
02 12 22 32 42 52 62 72 82 92
03 13 23 33 43 53 63 73 83 93
04 14 24 34 44 54 64 74 84 94